# Catch event status on dynamic Checkbox on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a list item generated dynamically. Within that, there is also a checkbox.

When one of the checkboxes is checked, I want bind its siblings into a table and remove if unchecked.

Here is my function that generates the Items:

```
function ItemsByCategory(CatId) {
            // alert('Function Scripts');
            $("#ItemsByCategory").empty();
            var html = "";



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../WebService.asmx/ItemsByCategory",
                data: "{'CatId':'" + CatId + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    try {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                            if (data.d[i].CatId != "") {

                                html += " <li class='Items'> ";
                                html += " <a class='app-menu__item' href='#'> ";
                                html += " <input type='checkbox' class='form-check mr-2' id='Item" + (i + 1) + "' /> ";
                                html += " <input type='hidden' class='ItemCatId' value='" + data.d[i].CatId + "' /> ";
                                html += " <input type='hidden' class='price' value='2' /> ";
                                html += " <span class='app-menu__label ItemName'>" + data.d[i].ItemName + "</span> ";
                                html += "  </a> ";
                                html += "  </li> ";



                                // html += "  <div class='fw-bold LandingTime'>" + data.d[i].LandingTime + " </div>";
                            }
                            else {
                                html += "<h4>No active Items</h4>";
                            }
                        }

                        $("#ItemsByCategory").append(html)
                    } catch (e) {
                        error(e);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, e) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
            });
        }
```

I call this function in `on click` event of Categories function and pass  Category `Id(CatId)` to it. that populates the Item of that clicked Category.

And Here is is the Html Table I want to bind.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="tile">
        <h3 class="tile-title"> Order List</h3>
        <div id="TblSelectedItems">
          <table class="table" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Unit Price($)</th>
                <th>Total</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>item 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control Qty" value="4" /> </td>
                <td>$1</td>
                <td>$4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>item 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control Qty" value="6" /> </td>
                <td>$2</td>
                <td>$12</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="totals">
              <tr>
                <th><strong> Total Amount :</strong></th>
                <td>$16</td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this to first identify which item is chcked /unchecked but it always alerts "itemx is checked" wheather its checked or unchecked.

So what is the best way to achieve this without `ASPnet` conrolls or events.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('id')
  alert("Cliked on : " + item);
  if ($('#item').ischecked = true) {
    alert(item + ' is checked');
  } else {
    alert(item + ' is unchecked');
  }
});
```

**NB:**  I asked a somewhat similar question here before, I received advise to use repeater, but the thing is I am not writing any code in the form's code behind and I am using any `aspnet` controls, just pure html and server side code in a webservice class.

Comment: The jQuery syntax to check if a checkbox is checked is: `var isChecked = $("#myId").is(':checked');`, or in your case: `var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');`

Answer (score 0):

Use `:checked` selector to check if check box is check or not with using jQuery object `$(this)` inside your `change` event.

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Example based upon your code:

```js
var html = "";
html += " <li class='Items'> ";
html += " <a class='app-menu__item' href='#'> ";
html += " <input type='checkbox' class='form-check mr-2' id='Item1" + "' /> ";
html += " <input type='hidden' class='ItemCatId' value='" + "CatId" + "' /> ";
html += " <input type='hidden' class='price' value='2' /> ";
html += " <span class='app-menu__label ItemName'>" + "ItemName" + "</span> ";
html += "  </a> ";
html += "  </li> ";
html += " <li class='Items'> ";
html += " <a class='app-menu__item' href='#'> ";
html += " <input type='checkbox' class='form-check mr-2' id='Item2" + "' /> ";
html += " <input type='hidden' class='ItemCatId' value='" + "CatId" + "' /> ";
html += " <input type='hidden' class='price' value='2' /> ";
html += " <span class='app-menu__label ItemName'>" + "ItemName" + "</span> ";
html += "  </a> ";
html += "  </li> ";
$("#ItemsByCategory").append(html); // Append your dynamic input

$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('id');
  //alert("Cliked on : " + item);

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert(item + ' is checked');
  } else {
    alert(item + ' is unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="tile">
        <h3 class="tile-title"> Order List</h3>
        <div id="TblSelectedItems">
          <table class="table" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Unit Price($)</th>
                <th>Total</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>item 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control Qty" value="4" /> </td>
                <td>$1</td>
                <td>$4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>item 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control Qty" value="6" /> </td>
                <td>$2</td>
                <td>$12</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="totals">
              <tr>
                <th><strong> Total Amount :</strong></th>
                <td>$16</td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ItemsByCategory"></div>
```